# how to access nested object property from an array in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

this is the json response i get in my dom

```
{ "resource": "services", "status": "success", "data": [ { "service_id": "0001", "service_name": "Buy Airtime", "service_type": "airtime" },  ] }
```

this is how my template

```
 <li v-for="service in responseObject">
          {{ service }}
        </li>
```

this is my script tag

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      status: false,
      responseObject: {}
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    try {
      let response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/blogs");
      this.responseObject = response.data;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

how can i display

```
service_id and service_name in my template
```

i've tried

```
service.data[0].service_name
```

but i'm not getting any response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this what you are missing

```
response.data.responseObject
```

modify your code

```
 async mounted() {
    try {
      let response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/blogs");
     this.responseObject = response.data.responseObject;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

then in your template

```
 <li
            v-for="service in  responseObject.data"
            :key="service.service_id"
          >
            {{ service.service_name }} - {{ service.service_id }}
          </li>
```

you should see an output

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```html
<li v-for="service in responseObject">
     {{ service.service_id }} - {{service.service_name}}
</li>
```

since `service` represent one item of the array

Answer (score 0):

You can access the child "data" array by adding dot notation to your v-for statement ("responseObject.data")-

```
    <ul>
      <li v-for="service in  responseObject.data"    :key="service.service_id">
        {{ service.service_name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/bsod_/pen/wvYwBrj

Answer (score 0):

You can try printing response.data Confirm if the correct data has been obtained